# The Odin Project - Sign up form - Help needed with CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I am trying to finish the "Sign up Form" project in The Odin Project and I have 1-2 issues that I would like help on.

I added a snippet below but the result is totally different from what I see in my laptop, but I just wanted you to have my code.

I also share with you my repository's URL: [Sign Up Form repository](https://github.com/georgan1987/Sign-Up-Form)

[image]

**Problem #1:** I don't know why this exceeds the *left div* that I created. It should have the same length as the side banner on the left div which writes "ODIN - SIGN UP FORM". I've tried many different things, none of them works.

**Problem #2:** I've no idea why the "Missing at least a special character" doesn't start a new line, but sticks with the previous line. If I remove this specific validation, all the other work (?) like I want to. I am not totally sure if there is any mistake on how i break the line in JavaScript.

**Problem #3:** In this project's site, we are advised to create our Sign Up Form in such way, so when we resize the window it doesn't crash. I have no idea how to do that. I know that media queries is (?) a way to do that, but I still haven't learnt about them in the Curriculum (Media queries are on a later stage).

```js
const firstName = document.querySelector('#first-name');
const lastName = document.querySelector('#last-name');
const email = document.querySelector('#email');
const phoneNumber = document.querySelector('#phone-number');
const password = document.querySelector('#password');
const passwordConfirm = document.querySelector('#confirm-password');

const firstNameError = document.querySelector('#fname-error');
const lastNameError = document.querySelector('#lname-error');
const emailError = document.querySelector('#email-error');
const phoneNumberError = document.querySelector('#phone-error');
const passwordError = document.querySelector('#pwd-error');
const passwordConfirmError = document.querySelector('#cpwd-error');

firstName.addEventListener('input', () => {
    if (firstName.value === ''){
        firstNameError.textContent = 'Please enter your first name!'
    } else {
        firstNameError.textContent = ''
    }
});

lastName.addEventListener('input', () => {
    if (lastName.value === ''){
        lastNameError.textContent = 'Please enter your first name!'
    } else {
        lastNameError.textContent = ''
    }
});

email.addEventListener('input', () => {
    if (email.validity.typeMismatch){
        emailError.textContent = 'Please enter a valid e-mail address! Example: john@smith.com';
    } else {
        emailError.textContent = ''
    }
});

phoneNumber.addEventListener('input', ()=> {
    if (phoneNumber.validity.patternMismatch){
        phoneNumberError.textContent = 'Please enter a 10-digit phone number';
    } else {
        phoneNumberError.textContent = ''
    }
});

password.addEventListener('input', ()=> {
    if (password.validity.patternMismatch){
        const currentValue = password.value;
        const regExpCap = /[A-Z]/g;
        const regExpDig = /[0-9]/g;
        const regExpSpecial = /[#?!@$%^&*-]/g;
        let result = '';


        if (regExpCap.test(currentValue)){
            result += '';
        } else {
            result += "Missing at least a capital letter";
            result += '\n';
        }


        if (regExpDig.test(currentValue)){
            result += '';
        } else {
            result += 'Missing at least a number';
            result += '\n';
        }

        if (regExpSpecial.test(currentValue)){
            result += '';
        } else {
            result += 'Missing at least a special character';
            result += '\n';
        }

        if (currentValue.length < 8){
            result += 'Password must be at least 8 characters long';
            result += '\n';
        } else {
            result += '';
        }
        
        passwordError.textContent = result;
    } else {
    passwordError.textContent = '';
    }
});

passwordConfirm.addEventListener('input', ()=> {
    if (password.value !== passwordConfirm.value) {
        passwordConfirmError.textContent = 'Passwords do not match';
    } else {
        passwordConfirmError.textContent = '';
    }
});
```

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    /* overflow-x: hidden;  */
  }
  
  
html body{
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    /* font-family: customFont; */
  }


.content {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100vw;
}

/* Side Hero part of the webpage */

.left {
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    position: relative;
    width: 60vw;
    min-width: 345px;
    background: url('background-pic.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center; 
    color: white;   
}

.side-hero {
    font-family: 'Bebas Neue', cursive;
    flex-grow: 1;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.527);
    line-height: 2rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.side-hero img {
    width: 5rem;
    height: auto;
    margin: 20px;
}

.side-hero h1 {
    font-size: 4rem;
    color: white;
    align-self: center;
 }

.side-hero > p {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.527);
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    color: white;
    margin: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.4rem;
}

/* Form section */

.right{
    display: flex;
    font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
    width: 100vw;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-grow: 2;
    background-color: rgba(231, 234, 236, 0.288)
}

.text {
    padding: 0.8rem 6rem 1rem 2rem;
    font-size: 2.0rem;
    width: 50vw;;
}

.form {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 0.8rem 2vw 3rem 2vw;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

form {
    display: flex;
    width: 60vw;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    gap: 1rem;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
}

.form-title {
    font-size: 2.0rem;
}

.input {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 1px;
    width: 15rem;
}

input {
    /* font-family: ; */
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
}

input:focus {
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.342);
    outline: none;
}

input:focus:valid {
    border: 2px solid rgba(0, 255, 64, 0.87);
}

input:focus:invalid {
    border: 2px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.945);
}


/* Submit Section */
button[type='submit']{
padding: 0.8rem 1.3rem;
font-size: 1.3rem;
/* background-color: ; */
border: none;
border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.253);
background-color: rgb(9, 191, 247);
color: white;
}

button[type='submit']:hover{
background-color: rgb(8, 101, 129);

}

.below-form {
    margin-top: 2rem;
    margin-left: 3rem;
}

.error {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    color: red;
    font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

/* Links */

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(173, 155, 173);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Abel&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Sign Up Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        
        <div class="left">
            <div class="side-hero">
                 <img src="./odin-lined.png" alt="The Odin Logo">
                 <h1>ODIN - Sign Up Form</h1>
                 <p>Photo by <a href='https://unsplash.com/@huzgin'>Huzaifa Ginwala</a> on <a href="https://unsplash.com">Unsplash</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="right">

            <div class="text">
                <p><b>This is not a real online service! You know you need something
                    like this in your life to help you realize your deepest dreams. </br>
                Sign up <em>now</em>  to get started.
                <br><br>
                You <em>know</em> you want to.</b>
                </p>
            </div>

            <div class="form">
                
                <p class="form-title"><b>Let's do this!</b></p>

                <form id="my-form">
                    <div class="input">
                        <label for="first-name">First Name</label>
                        <input id="first-name" name="first_name" type="text" autocomplete="off" required>
                        <p class="error" id="fname-error"></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="input">
                        <label for="last-name">Last Name</label>
                        <input id="last-name" name="last_name" type="text" required>
                        <p class="error" id="lname-error"></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="input">
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <input id="email" name="e_mail" type="email" required
                        autocomplete="on">
                        <p class="error" id="email-error"></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="input">
                        <label for="phone-number">Phone Number</label>
                        <input id="phone-number" name="phone_number" type="tel" 
                        pattern="[0-9]{10}" required>
                        <p class="error" id="phone-error"></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="input">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                        <input id="password" name="password" type="password" 
                        pattern='(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}' required>
                        <p class="error" id="pwd-error"></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="input">
                        <label for="confirm-password">Confirm Password</label>
                        <input id="confirm-password" type="password" name="confirm_password" 
                        pattern='(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}' required>
                        <p class="error" id="cpwd-error"></p>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>

            <div class="below-form">
                 <div class="create-button"><button type="submit" form="my-form"><strong>Create Account</strong></button></div>
                 <div class="log-in"><p>Already have an account? <a href="#">Log in</a></p></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do some minor changes in your code:

**Problem (1) Solution**: You need to change the value of css property **background-size** which is in **.left** class

Like this below code :-

```
background-size: contain
```

**Problem (2) Solution**: You need to change **"\n"** to **"br"** tag

Like this below code :-

```
result += '<br>';
```

**Problem (3) Solution**: You can use media queries like this below:-

```
@media (max-width: 600px) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

1.)why the left div exceeds its intended length could be due to the use of background-size: cover; property in the .left class. This property makes the background image cover the entire container, which could cause the container to extend beyond its intended width. You could try adjusting the background size property or using a different property to size the background image to fit the container. As the size of image also interferes with the sizing.

2.)replace /n with .

3.)for media queries search for a simple resource to start with online instead of copying the code